# How to figure out a query with too many subqueries

Tags: oracle, subquery

I've been given a big query to figure out. But there are so many subqueries that it's nearly impossible.The number of subqueries is about 15-20.What do you suggest I do?

Comment: I hope you are well aware of the tables they are querying on ! i think you need to start off from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I usually do when confronted with such monsters is:

1. Replace old style joins with new style ones
2. Modularize every non-trivial subquery into "virtual" tables using the with statement, for example:

> ```
> with
>  subquery1 as (select /*big query*/ ),
>  subquery2 as (select /*big query*/ )
> select *
> from ...
>      join subquery1
> where foo in (select foo from subquery2)
> ```

At that point some patterns emerge and more often than not the query can be rewritten in a sensible way.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is to issue an [explain plan](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm) to see how the DBMS would execute the query and go from there.